# Regex for Unicode characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to match "★★★★☆" by using regex in Python code. This is for Play Store thing.

- if I get ★★★☆☆ or ★★★★☆ or ★★★★★ i need to print as "High rated tickets"
  and
- if i get ★☆☆☆☆ or ★★☆☆☆ i need to print "Low rated "

My code is like this::

```
   if re.search(ur'[\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2606\u2606]+', d) \
    or re.search(ur'[\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2606]+', d)\
    or re.search(ur'[\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605]+', d):
       print "High rated playstore tickets"

   if re.search(u'[\u2605\u2605\u2606\\u2606\u2606]+',d) \
    or re.search(u'[\\u2605\\u2606\\u2606\\u2606\\u2606]+',d):

       print "Low rated tickets"
```

Not able to make a match particularly.
Please help

Comment: Why do you use a Regex for that at all? Just compare plain strings.

Comment: `[\u2605]{3,5}` for high rated and `[\u2605]{0,2}` for low rated?